# Is the lack of requirements such as functional and non-functional a risk?

Tags: risk-management, risk

If a project has forsaken to undertake a cycle of eliciting and documenting requirements, what level of risk does it introduce, how is this addressed and whom does it sit with?

Comment: How do you know what you're building if you have no requirements? Seems more like a blocker than a risk.

Comment: The requirements are not documented rather communicated verbally.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://pm.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: If you have no requirements, do you really have *project* or merely a task that someone asked you to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like it would be a HUGE risk.  Because it is huge, I would escalate it at the highest levels of the organization and it needs to be addressed by the project sponsor and project manager.